# Converting Internal Yammer group to External Yammer group and Vice versa

Tags: office-365, external-users, yammer

When creating new yammer groups we got 2 options, "Internal" & "External" groups as follow:-

[image]

Where most of the groups we have created are internal groups, but currently we want to add external users to a yammer group, so can i change a yammer group from internal to external ? as i did not find any option to do so from the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you trying is not possible, rather create a new external group and add the users in it.

"You can create a group that includes external users, called an external group. You must create the group as an external group - you can't change an existing internal group to be an external group."

[Create and manage external groups in Yammer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Yammer/work-with-external-users/create-and-manage-external-groups)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply and info, but my question was that i need the external user to be able to access the existing yammer discussions... so i have another question, since we can not change internal yammer group to external yammer group, then can I always create the group as external, and not add any external user to it,, so incase in the future we need to add external users we can do so .. what do u think?